# httpclient throws readtimeout exception after setting SO_TIMEOUT to infinity

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using httpclient for Client Side to connect Server. I did not set any timeout(readtimeout - SO_TIMEOUT). From the docs i found that if the timeout not specified then it interpreted as infinity(0).

But httpclient throws "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" exception within 20 to 30 seconds after connecting to server on client side. Also note: i am not facing this issue consistently.

What to do to resolve this? Help me.

Stack Trace :

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part.sendDispositionHeader(Part.java:220)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part.send(Part.java:308)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part.sendParts(Part.java:385)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity.writeRequest(MultipartRequestEntity.java:164)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
```

Code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpConnectionManager conn = new SimpleHttpConnectionManager(true);
conn.getParams().setConnectionTimeout(25000);
client.setHttpConnectionManager(conn);

PostMethod meth = new PostMethod(url);//url is server url
meth.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES);
Part p[] = new Part[parts.size()];//parts is an arraylist variable for server process params
p = (Part[])parts.toArray(p);
((PostMethod)meth).setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(p,meth.getParams()));
meth.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
HttpMethod method = (HttpMethod)meth;
int status =  client.executeMethod(method);
```

Exception thrown on client executeMethod

Thanks,
Ganesan

Comment: Please post the stack trace and the relevant code. Edit them into your question.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the comment. I have edited with Stack Trace.

Comment: But you haven't posted the relevant code.

Comment: @ELB code is posted. It is okay to analyse the problem?